# A Valid 'SELECT' SQL Statement Fails in Python But Works from SQLite Manager

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

This SQL statement works well in SQLite Manager:

```
select a.etl_name, a.start
from (
select etl_name,start,end
from etl_info_is
where (etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', start) ) in (
select etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', start) as start
from etl_info_is
where etl_name = 'My_Value'
except
select etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', schedule) as start
from etl_info_cron
where etl_name = 'My_Value' ) ) a join etl_info_is b
on (a.start between b.start and b.end and a.end between b.start and b.end)
where b.etl_name = 'My_Value' and
julianday('now') - julianday(a.start) <= 15
```

However, the same one fails on execution of the Python code with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/ISMD-jppilot.py/__main__.py", line 2241, in <module>
  File "/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/ISMD-jppilot.py/__main__.py", line 1926, in fillCRON_DSchd
  File "/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/ISMD-jppilot.py/__main__.py", line 1867, in get_ST_d_schd_seq
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

And this is the Python function where it fails:

```
def get_ST_d_schd_seq(key_f, seq_d_f):
    """ Get the start times of the double-scheduled seq """
    conn,c = connect(sqldb_loc)

    c.execute("""select a.etl_name, a.start
    from (
    select etl_name,start,end
    from etl_info_is
    where (etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', start) ) in (
    select etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', start) as start
    from etl_info_is
    where etl_name = ?
    except
    select etl_name, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', schedule) as start
    from etl_info_cron
    where etl_name = ? ) ) a join etl_info_is b
    on (a.start between b.start and b.end and a.end between b.start and b.end)
    where b.etl_name = ? and
    julianday('now') - julianday(a.start) <= 15""", (seq_d_f, seq_d_f, key_f))

    get_ST_d_schd_query = c.fetchall()
    close(conn,"Y")

    ST_d_schd_query_l = []
    for row in get_ST_d_schd_query:
        ST_d_schd = row[0]
        ST_d_schd = ST_d_schd.encode("utf-8")
        ST_d_schd = parse(ST_d_schd).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        ST_d_schd_query_l.append(ST_d_schd)

    return ST_d_schd_query_l
```

I've tried even executing the same code with hard-coded values regarding the content of the three variables - also tried using the '.format' method for substituting the variables so they're injected in a normal simpler way.

**EDIT_1:** It appears the reason why might be because of the SQLite version within Python 2.7.13. Can we make the SQL statement simpler so it can work on SQLite 3.6.20?

**EDIT_2:** I've installed Python 3.5 through the RedHad Software Collections but it appears the same version of SQLite is provided:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Sep 15 2016, 08:33:29)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.6.20'
```

Comment: Show your python code.

Comment: @jordanm: Here you're, jordanm - the post has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Row values](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) are supported since SQLite 3.15.0. The SQLite library in your Python is older (Check `sqlite_version` in the `sqlite3` module).

Comment: Python 2.7.13 (default, Feb  8 2017, 06:30:30)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version

'3.6.20'

Comment: It appears the SQLite version on the machine is '3.6.20'.

Comment: Using the SQLite Manager there's a different result which might be the reason:
select sqlite_version();  ----->> returned: 3.19.3 on the same DB - which appears to be the library version (from what I've understood).

Comment: CL., can we make the SQL statement simpler so it can work on SQLite 3.6.20?

Comment: That would be a different question. (And why don't you simply upgrade your Python?)

Comment: I use the official RHEL Software Compilations Repo on a RHEL 6 machine - so I can use Python 2.7.13. I'm not allowed to use external software (other than the one RedHat publishes through pkgs) though if there's a way to upgrade only the SQLite3 module of Python - that might do the trick. I've researched - but it appears that is not so straightforward task. Also - the machine does not have Internet access.

Comment: Through RedHat Software Collections I've managed to install Python 3.5 - but it still has the same SQLite version:
Python 3.5.1 (default, Sep 15 2016, 08:33:29)
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.6.20'